# What is error all about? and why?

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
class account(object):

    __duser_id = ''
    __duser_name =''
    __duser_no = ''

    def __init__(self, default, entry_name, password, user_id='', user_name='', user_no=''):
        if type(default) != bool:
            raise Exception("Error 0x1: type(default) is boolean ")
        if default == False:
            self.__user_id = user_id
            self.__user_name = user_name
            self.__user_no = user_no
        else:
            self.__user_id = __duser_id
            self.__user_name = __duser_name
            self.__user_no = __duser_no
        self.__entry_name = entry_name
        self.__password = password

    def dset(self, duser_id=__duser_id, duser_name=__duser_name, duser_no=__duser_no):
        __duser_id = duser_id
        __duser_name = duser_name
        __duser_no = duser_no
        return (__duser_id, __duser_name, __duser_no)

    def dget(self):
        return (__duser_id, __duser_name, __duser_no)

    def set(self, user_name=self.__user_name, user_id=self.__user_id, user_no=self.__user_no, password=self.__password):
        self.__user_id = user_id
        self.__user_name = user_name
        self.__user_no = user_no
        self.__password = password
        return (self.__user_id, self.__user_name, self.__user_no, self.password)

    def get(self):
        return (self.__user_id, self.__user_name, self.__user_no, self.password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gmail = account(default=True, entry_name='gmail', password='pass***')
    print(gmail.dget())
    print(gmail.get())
```

out put is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "interface.py", line 1, in 
>       class account(object):
>     File "interface.py", line 30, in account
>       def set(self, user_name=self.__user_name, user_id=self.__user_id, user_no=self.__user_no, password=self.__password):
>   NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You cannot use `self` in the method signatures.

Comment: Please don't write code like this. What are all those double underscores for? Why do you (in `dset`) take perfectly good parameters, assign them to *other* local names but this time with double underscore prefixes, then just return them? Why are you writing getters and setters at all?

Answer (score 0):

Ok o got it.
but there is another one i just changed code.

> This is a decorator with **arbitrary number of arguments and keyword
>   arguments**

```
def user_no_is_number(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
        if 'user_no' in kargs:
            if type(kargs['user_no']) != int:
                raise Exception('Error 1x0: user_no must contains only numbers.')
            else:
                return func(*args, **kargs)
    return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    @user_no_is_number
    def dset(user_id=None, user_name=None, user_no=None):
        if user_id:
            account.__duser_id = user_id
        if user_name:
            account.__duser_name = user_name
        if user_no:
            account.__duser_no = user_no
        return (account.__duser_id, account.__duser_name, account.__duser_no)
```

> but the dset() function return always None
>   ***I think there is problem with arbitrary keywords parameters. by using **kargs in decorator parameter it becomes dictionary and by again passing **kargs it just return values of that dictionary.***